# How do I "suggest" an unused wiki tag to be deleted?

Tags: support

Existing tag [error-messages](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-messages) is NOT used in ANY question.

Is it correct to assume that it is obsolete and candidate for removal? If so, how do I "suggest" such tag to be considered for removal ... and get "rewarded" for it somehow?

Answer (score 1):

There's no reward, no.

The tag will be automatically cleaned up by the system in the not too distant future (this happens on all SE sites for tags with no associated questions).

Comment: Thank you @Clive also! You confirm what I was suspecting. Would it be a good idea to raise a feature request about that on the overall meta site? Also: any hints/pointers to any help docu for more details about the "not too distant future"? Extra question: the answer to (this) 1 question causes some (like 10?) more questions. Should I rather post them on the overall meta site (the same issues exist everywhere I assume), or rather in our tiny meta.drupal corner (where reviewers, etc appear to me like way more "friendly" to newbees ...). I then leave it to you etc to MOVE them if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Tags that are not used from any question are automatically removed in 24 hours. There isn't any way to mark a tag as obsolete, so there isn't any reward for that. Tags that are used just from a question are automatically removed after 30 days (if I recall that correctly).

If there is any issue with existing tags, this meta site is the place where to raise issues about them.

Comment: Thanks @kiamialuno! to be honest I've noticed "quite a few" issues with existing tags, and I'd be happy to create an issue about them. But then I risk to run into another problem, which is that recently I read somewhere that you can only ask 50 question in 30 days (curiousity: is that per site or all sites?)... So how about this kind of work around: I create 1 question related to it, and then I keep adding 1 answer for each of such tags. Makes sense? If not: what else?